# can't push viewcontroller in slide out menu when touch button

Tags: ios, swift, pushviewcontroller

I use [KYDrawercontroller](https://github.com/ykyouhei/KYDrawerController) slide out menu I write code to push viewcontroller when touch button in uitableview but it not push
this is my code

```
@IBAction func m01(sender: AnyObject) {
    let mainnav = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("m02") as! UINavigationController //maindrawer
    let mainnav2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mm") as! page1ViewController //pagetopush
    mainnav.pushViewController(mainnav2, animated: true)

}
```

View in my project in https://github.com/salution/slide

Comment: you would need to upload a sample project on github or some place for people to check the code. Usually slide menu code need a lot of debugging at various places.

Comment: Ok wait I'll upload

Comment: https://github.com/salution/slide This my project github

Comment: you are using xcode 7.2 ?

Comment: No I use xcode 7.3.1

Comment: you have set the `KYDrawercontroller` in storyboard right ? i am on 7.2 so can't able to compile properly yet.

Answer (score 0):

use codes below to replace yours

```
@IBAction func m01(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("touched")
    let mainnav2 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mm") as! page1ViewController
    let rootVC = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController
    let childrenVC = rootVC?.childViewControllers
    let nc = childrenVC?.first as? UINavigationController
    if let DrawerTableViewController = navigationController?.parentViewController as? KYDrawerController{
        DrawerTableViewController.setDrawerState(.Closed, animated: true)
    }
    nc?.pushViewController(mainnav2, animated: true)

}
```

I prefer UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning protocol to present your UI effect

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it don't works I'll post my project git in question

Comment: Hi Yasuhiro Kondo, I have seen your code on git, see my answer

Comment: It didn't works it push in tableview not in navigation viewcontroller

Comment: I add a snapshot. It push in navigation controller.

Comment: View in table view is change I know but I want to change view in maincontroller not in slide menu sorry for not explain more

Comment: I don't know about KYDrawerController, I just try changing code. The key point is you get the exact navigation controller to push viewcontroller